Von Kármán momentum integral explanation
The Von Kármán momentum integral is the equation
$${\displaystyle {\frac {\tau _{w}}{\rho U^{2}}}={\frac {1}{U^{2}}}{\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}(U\delta _{1})+{\frac {\partial \delta _{2}}{\partial x}}+{\frac {2\delta _{2}+\delta _{1}}{U}}{\frac {\partial U}{\partial x}}+{\frac {v_{w}}{U}}}$$
with $${\displaystyle \tau _{w}=\mu \left({\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}}\right)_{y=0},\quad v_{w}=v(x,0,t),\quad \delta _{1}=\int _{0}^{\infty }\left(1-{\frac {u}{U}}\right)\,dy,\quad \delta _{2}=\int _{0}^{\infty }{\frac {u}{U}}\left(1-{\frac {u}{U}}\right)\,dy}$$
Where $U$ is the uniform velocity of outside of the boundary layer, $u$ is the local velocity in the $x$ direction inside the boundary layer and $v_w$ is the suction velocity at the wall, $\mu$ is viscosity and $\rho$ is the density of the fluid.
This is the "integral equation" of the Navier-Stokes equation (actually Prandtl equations), but it is still a differential equation.

As it is a differential equation, what function do we solve it for?

What is the SI unit of the momentum thickness $\delta_2$?



What is the solution to this differential equation? As far as I know, the Navier-Stokes equations don’t have an analytic general solution, so why would this equation have one?

What is the SI unit of the momentum thickness $\delta_2$? To make this question self-contained, you need to define $U$, $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$, $\rho$, $\tau_w$, and $v_w$. You can assume that the meanings of $t$ and $x$ are obvious, but the meaning of everything else is not.

@Ghoster I made an edit. But in theory we solve the NS equations to obtain the 4 scalar fields, velocities in x,y,z and the pressure. I am curious for what do we solve this equation.

Why isn’t it clear to you from their definitions that $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ are lengths?

I am curious for what do we solve this equation. I’m not familiar with this equation, but I would assume that you’re solving it for $U(x,t)$. What seems confusing is that $\delta_1$, and probably also $\delta_2$, are apparently functions of $t$, so I don’t see how you can solve one equation for three functions.

@Ghoster Thanks. That was my thought, but the $\delta_2$ has the name momentum thickness, and represents the momentum lost due to the friction with the object, so I thought it has the units of momentum , or energy, but it is indeed clear from its definition that it has dimensions of $y$ i.e. lenght.

@Ghoster No, I don't think that anything here is a function of time, it is stationary flow so nothing changes in time. And usually we have $U$ because we can solve for that using potential flow theory.

If $\delta_1$ isn’t a function of time, why would it be inside rather than outside the time derivative?

I don't think that anything here is a function of time. That doesn’t make sense, given the time derivative term.

@Ghoster Ah, you are right. Sorry. We learned it only for stationary flow, so that first term vanishes.

It also seems clear from the second and third terms on the right side of the equation that $\delta_2$ and $U$ are both functions of $x$, so you’ve got multiple unknown functions of $x$ even in the time-independent case.

But given that they’re related by the integral defining $\delta_2$, maybe that makes things solvable. I’ve one enough guessing. I’ll let you wait for an answer by someone who understands this stuff.
